# The minimum number of moves required such that an array is non-decreasing

Tags: arrays

I am required to count the minimum number of moves required such that an array is non-decreasing. In a move, we are able to split a single integer in place (so that when splitting arr[i], they become arr[i] and arr[i+1]) in any way, eg 4 could be split so that it becomes either (1,3) or (2,2). Thereby the length of the array increases by 1 in each move.

For example, consider the array [5, 2, 3]. In our first move, we could split 5 such that our array becomes [3, 2, 2, 3] and in our second move we could split 3, and our array would become [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]. Hence, the minimum number of moves for the array [5, 2, 3] such that the array is non-decreasing is 2.

I've currently come up with this.

```
def min_moves(x):
    moves = 0
    index = 2
    while index < len(x) + 1:
        if x[-index] > x[-index + 1]:
            moves += 1
            split1 = x[-index] // 2
            split2 = x[-index] - split1
            x = x[:-index] + [split1, split2] + x[-index + 1:]
 
        else:
            index += 1
        
    return moves
```

However, this fails in cases such as when the input is [2, 7, 3]. In the case of my algorithm, the array would become [2, 3, 4, 3] after the first move. However, to find the minimum solution it should be [2, 4, 3, 3] after the first move. Any hints in the right direction would be appreciated. I believe I'm going about the question in slightly the wrong way as I do not need to actually perform the splits; rather I simply need to keep count of the minimum number of splits. A greedy approach seems like the logical route but I'm not really sure how to go about it. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: *"This returns the right minimum number of moves"*: Your algorithm is not correct. Try [2,7,3].

Comment: Yes, you are right, guess I didn't test it enough. Do you have any hints on how I could work towards a correct solution?

Comment: You'll have to rewrite your question.

Comment: I've edited it to say my code is incorrect. Is that all you were expecting me to edit or was the question itself unclear?

Comment: @trincot was there anything else you were expecting me to rewrite?

Comment: Just add an example of where your code fails to return the right result. That's all. Hope someone will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go from the right, and apart from the right-most number, break each number into the smallest number of pieces possible, with the left-most number as large as possible. That means, if the number to the right was broken into pieces and its left-most number was M, then you break the current number into `k=ceil(a[i]/M)` pieces, and its left-most number is `floor(a[i]/k)`. It's easy to prove that these choices are without loss of generality optimal, because any other valid choice would result in the left-most number being smaller (and hence the remaining problem at least as hard).

For example: `5 2 3`:

- 3 is not split, as it is the right-most number
- 2 is split into ceil(2/3) = 1 piece (ie: not split).
- 5 is split into ceil(5/2) = 3 pieces (ie: split twice), and its left-most piece is floor(5/3)=1.

So the total number of splits is 2.

Here's a python solution:

```
def parts(xs):
    M = xs[-1]
    s = 0
    for i in range(len(xs)-2, -1, -1):
        k = (xs[i] + M - 1) // M
        s += k - 1
        M = xs[i] // k
    return s

print(parts([5, 2, 3]))
print(parts([2, 7, 3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Algorithm

1. If current number is more than next number, divide current by 2.
   Increment count of moves.
2. Return an array of pairs

   ```js
   [floor(current number/2), current number - floor(current number/2)]
   ```
3. Go back to #1 if it is still true otherwise...
4. Return current number
5. Next iteration go back to #1
6. Once array is finished, check if it is in non-decreasing order
7. If not, recursively call function and pass in the array then flatten it when returned
8. Return array when it is non-decreasing order.

```js
function nonDecreasing(array) {
  let result = array.flatMap((num, idx, arr) => {
    let seg;
    // As long as the current number is more than the number ahead of it...
      while (num > arr[idx + 1]) {
        // Increment count
        i++;
        // Get a half of current number
        seg = Math.floor(num / 2);
        // Current number is now half or half+1
        num = num - seg;
        // Return both segment and current number in an array (will be flattened) 
        return [seg, num];
      }
    // Otherwise just return current number
    return num;
  });
  // If array is not in non-decreasing order...
  if (!checkOrder(result)) {
    // Recursively call nonDecreasing() passing in array and flatten when returned
    result = nonDecreasing(result).flat();
  }
  return result;
}
```

```js
function checkOrder(array) {
  let result = array.flatMap((num, idx, arr) => arr[idx+1] && num <= arr[idx+1] ? [] : !arr[idx+1] ? true : false);
  return result[0];
}

let i = 0;
function nonDecreasing(array) {
  let result = array.flatMap((num, idx, arr) => {
    let seg;
    while (num > arr[idx + 1]) {
      i++;
      seg = Math.floor(num / 2);
      num = num - seg;
      return [seg, num];
    }
    return num;
  });
  if (!checkOrder(result)) {
    result = nonDecreasing(result).flat();
  }
  return result;
}

let A = [5, 2, 3];
console.log(JSON.stringify(nonDecreasing(A)), i);

let B = [8, 1, 5, 4, 6];
console.log(JSON.stringify(nonDecreasing(B)), i);

let C = [2, 7, 3];
console.log(JSON.stringify(nonDecreasing(C)), i);
```